# EF Core query a postgreSQL user-defined enum type

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, user-defined-types

I have a column with a UDT in my table and when I try to query it with EF Core the database throws an error

> operator does not exist: example_type = text

This doesn't work:

```
var type = ExampleType.ExampleValue;
    
query.Where(e => e.Type == type)...
```

But if I pass it directly it works

```
query.Where(e => e.Type == ExampleType.ExampleValue)...
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? How do you mapped enum to UDT, which documentation do you use? Do you read that [Enum Type Mapping](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/enum.html?tabs=tabid-1)?

Comment: Have you tried `query.Where(ExampleType e => e.Type == type)`?